# sum values of a column pandas and drop the repeated ones

Tags: python, pandas, sum

i have  a data frame i need to sum the value of g and drop the replicated ones like this
int:

```
a    b      c   d   e   f   g   
6   2011    1   1   0   0   0
6   2011    1   1   0   0   0
6   2011    1   1   0   0   7
6   2011    1   1   0   0   2
6   2011    1   1   0   0   0
7   2012    1   1   0   0   5
7   2012    1   1   0   0   8
```

i know that for drop row we can use df.drop_duplicates() but i don't know how can i sum and drop
    out:

```
a    b      c   d   e   f   g

6   2011    1   1   0   0   9
7   2012    1   1   0   0   13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group on the other columns and sum:

```
df.groupby(list('abcdef'), as_index=False)['g'].sum()
Out: 
   a     b  c  d  e  f   g
0  6  2011  1  1  0  0   9
1  7  2012  1  1  0  0  13
```

`list('abcdef')` is a short way of writing `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`.

If you don't want to specify all the column names, you can use `Index.difference`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['g']).tolist(), as_index=False).sum()
Out: 
   a     b  c  d  e  f   g
0  6  2011  1  1  0  0   9
1  7  2012  1  1  0  0  13
```